# Git rebase onto orphan results in binary file conflict

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have a branch `master` (with e.g. 2 commits `A` adds `logo.png`, `B` deletes `logo.png`) which I want to rebase onto a completely new branch `new-master` (where no file paths are touched from `master`).

```
git checkout master
git checkout --orphan new-master
rm -rf ./* # Remove everything which is still here and untracked...
git commit --allow-empty "Init new"

git checkout master && git rebase new-master
```

Git stops the rebase after the first "pick A" (adds `logo.png`) complaining about

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        logo.png
```

Why can't it just add the commit `B` on top of `A`. What is going on? Why is there any conflict??

**I use git on windows, and it seems it might have something to do with time stamps**

**It seem LFS tries to check my .gitattibutes after each PICK and touches the files**

```
Encountered 10 file(s) that should have been pointers, but weren't
```

And therefore I get always changes... ?

Comment: If you really used `rm -rf` instead of `git rm -r`: you made a commit in the new orphan branch that already had all the same files as the last commit in `master`. The rest then makes sense.

Comment: It would be easy to confirm that hypothesis. Just use `git ls-tree` to find out what’s in the “Init new” commit. — By the way, the failure to check what’s happening or about to happen with `git status` and/or `git ls-files` at every step is a concern. Like driving with your eyes closed...